# Run graphic content with crontab (xcowsay)

Tags: bash, cron

I'm trying to open a random fortune every hour with xcowsay, the problem is that I tried to set the DISPLAY environment variable before running the command:

`* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && fortune -a | xcowsay`

But it doesn't work, I've tried to launch it with a script but it doesn't change anything, the cow doesn't show up and there is nothing.

Do you have any advice ?

Thank you by advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

- `crontab` only expects one command. It cannot invoke multiple commands with pipe.
- `crontab` doesn't know the path to `fortune` and `xcowsay`.

Then would you please try instead:

```
* * * * * bash -c 'export DISPLAY=:0 && /usr/games/fortune -a | /usr/games/xcowsay'
```